# How to add description to object properties

Tags: javascript, documentation, jsdoc

I have defined a new YSDK type using this syntax

```js
/**
 * @typedef {{
 *     environment: {
 *          app: {
 *              id: string
 *          },
 *          browser: {
 *              lang: string,
 *          },
 *          i18n: {
 *              lang: string,
 *              tld: string
 *          },
 *          payload?: string
 *     }
 * }} YSDK
 */
```

I know that I can add description if I use [this syntax](https://jsdoc.app/tags-typedef.html)

```
/**
 * The complete Triforce, or one or more components of the Triforce.
 * @typedef {Object} WishGranter~Triforce
 * @property {boolean} hasCourage - Indicates whether the Courage component is present.
 * @property {boolean} hasPower - Indicates whether the Power component is present.
 * @property {boolean} hasWisdom - Indicates whether the Wisdom component is present.
 */
```

Is there a way to add a description to the properties of the object in the form in which I defined them?